# What is the slope of the line tangent to $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus

If $c=3$ shows that the mean value theorem applies to $f(x)$ on $-2\lt x\lt8$, what is the slope of the line tangent to $f(x)$ at $x=3$?

Two points on $f(x)$ are $(-2,5)$ and $(8,-3)$.

Please explain as much as possible. Also include the answer if you want to be chosen as best answer. I haven't been able to solve this for a week.
Thank you.

Comment: Well, let's start with the statement of the mean value theorem: The usual notation and conclusion is that there exists a $c$ for which $$f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}$$

Comment: Yeah. But how is a tangent line related to the mean value theorem?

Comment: The tangent line is related to the derivative.

Comment: I don't understand? Can you please work it out for me. I have to have this solved by tomorrow in my final exam review?

Comment: What is $c$, and how is $c=3$ related to the problem? Can you state the problem fully?

Comment: That's the exact problem. The issue is that I don't know what c=3 has to do with anything...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tangent line of $f(x)$ at $x=x_0$ is：

$y-f(x_0)=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$

therefore the slope of the tangent line at $x=x_0$ is $f'(x_0)$. From now on, we just need to calculate $f'(3)$.

The mean value theorem yields that

$f'(3)=\dfrac{f(8)-f(2)}{8-(-2)}=\dfrac{(-3)-5}{8-(-2)}=-\dfrac{4}{5}$

which completes the proof.